# Proposals and their rule in English

Tags: grammaticality

Please take a look at these sentences:

A: *He recommends/urges (that) she goes to a doctor.*
B: *The doctor recommended (that) he gives up smoking.*
C: *It is essential (that) you are given your medication by a properly qualified nurse.*

Which of those sentences is correct grammatically?

Comment: You have asked that same question on another grammar website, where you were told that they are perfectly grammatical. They are alternatives to the mandative subjunctive construction, e.g. _The doctor recommended (that) he give up smoking_.

Comment: Yeah, you said that but I can't accept it that way. According to your scenario, "She go to school" is also perfectly grammatical because it's an alternative to "she goes to school".

Comment: I'd like to hear StoneyB's opinion in this case.

Comment: "It is essential that he **go** to school" is a mandative subjunctive construction (plain verb-form), and "It is essential that he **goes** to school" is the equivalent non-subjunctive. The subjunctive is used more in AmE than BrE, and it is more formal than the non-subjunctive. But both are fine -- it's as simple as that

Comment: Since you ask, BillJ is entirely correct.

Comment: Thanks so much StoneyB for your response. Thanks to BillJ too. The only vague point that remains is: Is it right that using proposals rule in **BrE** is optional in both formal and informal styles, but in **AmE**, it's a must in formal language but optional in less-formal language?